# Can't get my navigation menu in the center of the page

Tags: menu, center

The navigation menu is not centered. I have tried many methods of getting it to be centered, but none worked.

HTML

```
<div id="nav-bar">
<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a> </li>    
<li> <a href="servicii.html">Servicii</a> </li>    
<li> <a href="portofoliu.html">Portofoliu</a> </li>    
<li> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a> </li>
```

CSS

```
#nav-bar li a {
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Myriad Pro", "Myriad Pro Cond", "Myriad Pro Light", Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;

#nav-bar {
text-transform: uppercase;
list-style: none;
padding: 23px 0 23px 0;
background-image: url(../images/nav-bar.jpg);

#nav-bar li {
float: left;
margin-right: 58px;
margin-left: 58px;
margin-top: -8px;
}
```

Comment: http://iceimg.com/HVnt92__mFLf/img.jpg   This is the image of the layoyut!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/NLfaz/4/

```
#nav-bar {
   text-align: center;
}

#nav-bar li {
   float: left;  /* removed this line */
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, you weren't closing some of your css with `}` , so I added those in

Comment: Thanks, It really worked, I would give you reputation, but I'm new in here so .. sorry! :D